# How can I filter items based on whether a file has been uploaded using Podio itself or Google Sheet's importXML?

Tags: search, filter, google-sheets, upload, podio

I have items in podio that need a file to be uploaded. Most have a file, but not all do and I need to upload files to those that are missing one. Right now my only solution is to click on every item individually and see if there's a file uploaded, which takes a while. I was hoping to automate this by creating a filter to put the items that don't have files uploaded at the top, for example. If not, I was hoping to use the importXML function in Google Sheets to tell me whether a file is attached to an item

- I've tried looking for a filter; there's none
- I've tried creating a tag; that doesn't create the same function I need
- I've tried using importXML, but I don't think it works because of Podio's login

Comment: Please edit your question to be a little less ambiguous about what you have done, and what it is that you want to achieve. _"Right now my only solution is to click on every item individually and see if there's a file uploaded, which takes a while. "_- where are you clicking, Podio or Google Sheets? How do you determine whether there is a file or not, visually/by file name? Podio says they integrate with Google Drive? Have you asked this question at Podio?

Answer (score 0):

Podio does not support filtering by file attached to item, sorry.